# copying & pasting a row n times based on corresponding number in a cell within that row

Tags: unix, awk

Say I have a csv file with "," as the field separator in this format:

```
0.051278,1,0,0,4,0,1,2
0.024788,1,7,0,0,0,0,0
0.042316,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
```

What I want to do is copy and paste each row n times were n is the number in the first column times 100. So the first row would appear 5 times, the second row 2 times, the third row 4 times, and so on.

Desired output:

```
0.051278,1,0,0,4,0,1,2
0.051278,1,0,0,4,0,1,2
0.051278,1,0,0,4,0,1,2
0.051278,1,0,0,4,0,1,2
0.051278,1,0,0,4,0,1,2
0.024788,1,7,0,0,0,0,0
0.024788,1,7,0,0,0,0,0
0.042316,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
0.042316,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
0.042316,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
0.042316,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
```

The actual data file has over 2000 rows and the decimal number in the first line ranges anywhere from .03(more decimal places) to .7(more decimal places). Numbers would have to be rounded as you can't copy and paste a row 2.5 times. So, something like .25 would go to .3 and .24 would go to .2

Comment: Show the actual input format and not a cleaned up version please (or, if the original input is really unclear show *both*). Have you tried anything for this yet?

Comment: I haven't, I've tried Vim's multiple paste command but that would take me a while considering there are 2000+ rows.

Comment: Please clean up your question to give 1 sample input file and the expected output. Right now we have you saying your input is comma separated and showing an example that isn't along with what is presumably the expected output for that input and then followed by some other set of input that IS comma-separated but doesn't have the same values as the first input and has no associated expected output. It's a mess. Just post some accurate, testable, real, consistent, sample input and expected output, that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=0;i<$1*100;i++)print}' input.txt
```

In the above solution 0.0234 and 0.0236 would get print 23 times. Is this what you want?

If you need rounded values, I suggest to use something like this:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=0;i<int($1*100+.5);i++)print}' input.txt
```

Thanks [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579758/copying-pasting-a-row-n-times-based-on-corresponding-number-in-a-cell-within-t/30580216?noredirect=1#comment49230714_30580216)!

Comment: It does not round at all.

Comment: 5 is still lower than 5.33453 (for example) :) IMHO rounding is not required.

Comment: Probably I misunderstood that part. Let me add a solution which takes this into account.

Comment: It appears to round. .236 results in 24 lines and .149 in 15 lines pasted. Actually, it seems to add 1 additional line no matter what the decimal. 0.161 resulted in 17 lines.

Comment: Have added something that rounds properly.

Comment: Isn't it enough to add `0.5` when calling `int()` instead of using that rounding function? `int(0.234*100+0.5) = 23` while `int(0.238*100+0.5) = 24`.

Comment: @EdMorton Indeed! (especially since that function performs *unbiased* rounding)..

Comment: @EdMorton *unbiased rounding* - What the hell!! :) Never heard that before.

Comment: Yeah its funny how we tend to glibbly say "round" when there's about 20 different variants (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) with sometimes many names for the same variant! Shouldn't that second function be `awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=int($1*100+0.5);i++)print}'`?

Comment: Will need to read that Wikipedia article! Yeah, I accidently posted my debug version! Fixed that.